# Routing assertions not recognizing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to set up a custom route in my rails engine that maps to my controller action but when testing the route it says no route matches it.

**routes.rb**

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
    resources :lead_emails, except: [:new, :edit, :show]
    get 'lead_emails/send_out_emails/:idea_id', to: 'lead_emails#send_out_emails', as: 'send_out_emails'
end
```

**rake routes**

```
Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
    lead_emails GET    /lead_emails(.:format)                          my_engine/lead_emails#index
                POST   /lead_emails(.:format)                          my_engine/lead_emails#create
     lead_email PATCH  /lead_emails/:id(.:format)                      my_engine/lead_emails#update
                PUT    /lead_emails/:id(.:format)                      my_engine/lead_emails#update
                DELETE /lead_emails/:id(.:format)                      my_engine/lead_emails#destroy
send_out_emails GET    /lead_emails/send_out_emails/:idea_id(.:format) my_engine/lead_emails#send_out_emails
```

I have tried testing this route a variety of ways

```
test "should generate send out emails route" do
      assert_generates( 'lead_emails/send_out_emails/1',
      {controller: 'my_engine/lead_emails', action: 'send_out_emails', idea_id: "1"})
end

ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
No route matches {:action=>"send_out_emails", :controller=>"my_engine/lead_emails", :idea_id=>"1"}


test "should recognize send out emails route should exist" do
    assert_recognizes(
          {controller: 'my_engine/lead_emails', action: 'send_out_emails', idea_id: "1"},
          'lead_emails/send_out_emails/1')
end

No route matches "/lead_emails/send_out_emails/1"
```

the crazy thing is that if i use the helper method it works

```
test "should send out emails" do   
    get send_out_emails_path(@idea.id)
    assert_response :success 
end
```

This test passes. So how can I test the this route? seems pretty strait forward but it has been driving me crazy! I have tried with and without the my_engine prefix for the controller but has not helped any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why this works but it works. I added a variable to my setup method in my test

```
setup do
    @routes = MyEngine::Engine.routes
end
```

Now every test works.